# Is this multithreaded code safe (OpenMP)

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I am working on some code which loads a series of images in parallel.  The median values of the images need to be normalized to match the background of all of the other images.  To do this I take one of the images an compute its median.  I then shift the values of all the other images medians to match that.  I didn't want the overhead of loading the first image in serial so I came up with the following code.

```
pixel_t bg;
bool bgset = false;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
for(size_t i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
{
    image_t* img = load(list->file_names[i]);
    if(bias)
        image_subtract_dark(img, bias);
    if(dflat)
        image_subtract_dark(img, dflat);

    if(!bgset)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            if(!bgset)
            {
                stack_assert(image_median(img, &bg) == SUCCESS, "Out of Memory");
                bgset = true;
                #pragma omp flush(bgset)
            }
        }
    }

    stack_assert(image_normalize_median(img, bg) == SUCCESS, "Out of Memory");

    #pragma omp critical
    {   
        stack_printf("Stacking flat frame [%s]\n", list->file_names[i]);
        stack_assert(accumulator_add(accum, img) == SUCCESS, 
                "Accumulation Error, (May be out of Memory)");
    }
    image_free(img);
}
```

As you can see here I first avoid the overhead of barriers and cirticical sections by checking of bgset is false.  bgset will be true most of the time after the first threads makes it through that section.  Then inside the first if statement I check bgset again inside of that critical section in case another thread happened to change it while the current one was waiting to go into the critical section.  Finally if my thread is the one to set bg it will enter the region, set the background, set the flag, and flush its value.  What I am wondering is if this is a case where I would need to flush?  Also overall did I go about this correctly?